# Py: Create a folder hierarchy with nested folders

Tags: python-3.x, directory, hierarchy

I am trying to automate a creation of a project folder structure with the following:

```
..\Data
..\Data\GPS
..\Data\Tabular
..\Data\Working
..\Documents
..\Documents\Documentation
..\Documents\Pics_Graphics
..\Products
```

And, over complicating things, this is what I've come with...which...works....but surely there's a way to just include my hierarchy as a list and loop through it while maintaining the "if exists skip" condition? I've looked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28715/script-for-creating-a-hierarchy-of-directories? which has a similar result but I can't untangle the provided list in that case, which is based on a counter.

```
import os
import errno
data = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Data'
try:
    os.makedirs(data)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % data)

datagps = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Data//GPS'
try:
    os.makedirs(datagps)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % datagps)

dataworking = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Data//Working'
try:
    os.makedirs(dataworking)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % dataworking)

datatab = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Data//Tabular'
try:
    os.makedirs(datatab)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % datatab)

docs = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Documents'
try:
    os.makedirs(docs)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % docs)

document = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Documents//Documentation'
try:
    os.makedirs(document)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % document)

pics = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Documents//Pics_Graphics'
try:
    os.makedirs(pics)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % pics)

prod = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//Products'
try:
    os.makedirs(prod)
except OSError as exception:
    if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    else:
        print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % prod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop. Depending on how deep your directories are, and for practicality reasons, you could use a nested for loop aswell.

So you could just do:

```
directories = ['Data','GPS','Data//GPS',....,'Products']
basedirectory = 'C://temp//Pro_Folder_Structure//'
for (i in range (len (directories)):
    newDir = basedirectory + directories[i]
    try:
        os.makedirs(newDir)
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
           raise
        else:
           print ("\nBE CAREFUL! Directory %s already exists." % newDir)
```

Comment: changed (i  to i with no paranthesis in front of it an it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Haha yeah, I've been programming too much in Java lately, hence too many brackets. No problem, glad I could help!